# Invoke click handler on class selector and retrieve the ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML Table with each row:

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href='#' id='1' class='delete'>delete</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href='#' id='2' class='delete'>delete</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href='#' id='3' class='delete'>delete</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

I need a jQuery function that gets the id when the click handler is called:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  //Get id and set to num
  var num = XXXXX //ID
  //Invoke ajax request using num
  jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'num': num}, url:'/user/delete',success:function(data,textStatus){deletePicture(num);;},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});
});
```

Two questions:
1) How do I get the ID
2) Is the ajax success callback correct?

Comment: You should rephrase your issue more clearly, maybe with some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success callback looks fine (provided that `deletePicture` is defined elsewhere).

To get the id, you just need `this.id`:

```
var num = this.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

var num = $(this).attr('id') I believe?